# mode of displaying products in a shopping cart

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing my own shopping cart with asp.net mvc from scratch. But there is a functionality that I see in most shopping cart that I kind of admire but I dont know how this is done.

I notice that when you visit a shopping cart information of the products are seen first then you see a circular loading leting you know that the images are loading.

when the user starts scrolling the images that appearing one by one.

Please can someone explain to me how this is done. Also why is the text and image not gotten at once.

Is it because of bandwith or speed.

I would like to implement this in my own shopping cart. So I looking for the best design model for a great user experience.

Here is a website that does that : www.konga.com

Thanks alot.

Comment: Your should ask for help if some details arent working. Not to let implement your features.

Comment: I wasnt asking for people to implement. I am asking for advice on what could solve the problem

Comment: I did not have an idea of how to go about it, that is the reason why I asked in the first instance. Well I just got an answer view it below. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this while doing an intense research from another forum.

Jquery lazy load plugin.

another  is unveil lazy load plugin

https://github.com/luis-almeida/unveil